# resizing from paintComponent method

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, preferredsize

I have this little code

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Test();
}

Test() {
    getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());

    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}

private class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        setSize(640, 480);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
        g.fillRect(20, 20, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

Unfortunately **the frame is not resized** to the size of the nested panel after calling `pack()`. I already read the related answers for this topic, but none of them helped. Could you provide me a solution, please?

Comment: Attempting to change the state of the GUI within `paintComponent(Graphics)` will lead to trouble.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `pack()` is executed the panel is still invisible and its `paintComponent()` was not executed and as a result `setPreferredSize()` wasnt executed as well.

But don't call `setPreferredSize` from `paintComponent()`. Do your painting in `paintComponent` nothing else. Avoid putting program logic into that method. Painting operations should be fast and optimized for better performance and user experience. See [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.

Override panel's `getPrefferedSize()`, or at least execute setPrefferedSize before `pack()`.

Also see [Should I avoid the use of set[Preferred|Maximum|Minimum]Size methods in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/1048330).

Answer (score 2):

```
    public MyPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640, 480));
    }
```

Comment: -1 for setPreferredSize without need (note: there's extremely rare contexts where such a need might exist :-)